# In yii 1.1.x set relations if table is related twice

Tags: php, database, yii

My table Tour has 2 fields related User table : user_id(Owner of Tour) and modified_by( who modified it last)
And problem is that I do not know how to set relations to them.
If I write :

```
public function relations()
{
  return array(
    'belongs_to_modified_by_user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'modified_by'),
    'belongs_to_user_id_user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
  )
}
```

I get error :

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'user'
```

How correctly ?

I am tring to make it, but it fails :

```
public function relations()
{
  return array(
    'belongs_to_modified_by_user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'modified_by', 'alias' => 'modi' ),
    'belongs_to_user_id_user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id', 'alias' => 'touser' ),
    'belongs_to_category' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Category', 'category_id'),
    'belongs_to_region' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Region', 'region_id'),
    'belongs_to_subregion' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Subregion', 'subregion_id'),
    'belongs_to_state' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'State', 'state_id'),
  );
}
```

...

```
In method for data retrieving:
  $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
  $criteria->alias = 'T';
  $criteria->with[] = 'belongs_to_modified_by_user';
  $criteria->with[] = 'belongs_to_user_id_user';
  $criteria->with[] = 'belongs_to_category';
  $criteria->with[] = 'belongs_to_region';
  $criteria->with[] = 'belongs_to_subregion';
  $criteria->with[] = 'belongs_to_state';

But I get error :
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'user'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `T`.`id`) FROM `tyb_tour` `T` LEFT JOIN tyb_category as c ON c.id = T.category_id LEFT OUTER JOIN `tbl_users` `user` ON (`T`.`modified_by`=`user`.`id`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `tbl_profiles` `profile` ON (`profile`.`user_id`=`user`.`id`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `tbl_users` `user` ON (`T`.`user_id`=`user`.`id`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `tbl_profiles` `profile` ON (`profile`.`user_id`=`user`.`id`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `tyb_category` `belongs_to_category` ON (`T`.`category_id`=`belongs_to_category`.`id`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `tyb_region` `belongs_to_region` ON (`T`.`region_id`=`belongs_to_region`.`id`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `tyb_subregion` `belongs_to_subregion` ON (`T`.`subregion_id`=`belongs_to_subregion`.`id`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `tyb_state` `belongs_to_state` ON (`T`.`state_id`=`belongs_to_state`.`id`) WHERE (T.user_id=:ycp0). Bound with :ycp0='2'
```

If my format for alias correct ?

Comment: your code is correct, this error is not related to these relations at all, please try to trace your code and know exactly what line is throwing this error

Answer (score 1):

try with `alias name`

like that

```
return array(
    'belongs_to_modified_by_user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'modified_by', 'alias' => 'modi'),
    'belongs_to_user_id_user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id', 'alias' => 'touser'),
```